# How to specify a CAML Query to return items that have any of two site columns?

Tags: caml-query, caml, caml-renderpattern, camlviewfields

I want to define a query to return items that satisfy the following :-

1. if any item have a CT & login user = site column

so i wrote the following :-

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >
        <![CDATA[
        <Where>
  <Or>
     <And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />
           <Value Type="Text">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" />
           <Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
     <And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />
          <Value Type="Text">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" />
           <Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
  </Or>
</Where>]]>

        </property>
```

but this will not return any result. i wrote this query inside a content query web part .. under the QueryOverride tag and i am providing the CT id +site columns internal names..

**EDIt**

Now i tried this :-

```
        <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >
         <![CDATA[
        <Where>
  <Or>
     <And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" />
    <Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
     <And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" />
    <Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
  </Or>
</Where>]]>
        </property>
```

I can confirm that the site column names are the internal names + the content Types ids are correct...

**EDIT-2**

now i manage to get the CAML tool working , so i wrote the query as follow (i define to use the SP object model):-

[image]

but the result will be empty. as i said i am providing the correct site columns internal names, and the content type ids, so can anyone adivce why i am not getting any results ? and i did not see any exception at the same time ..

Thanks

Comment: you haven't mentioned User name's value anywhere in query. 


<FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" />
           <Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" />[UserValue]</Value>

Replace [UserValue] with the ID of user.

Comment: @Gaurravs now i do not want to specify certain user id , instead i want to get the login user  ,, so should i write [Me]  ? or it will not work ?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, you have to pass logged in user's name using jquery

Comment: @Gaurravs based on the below answer using "<UserID /> tag " will do this for me ..

Comment: refer this blog for how to write such type of query http://blog.riccardocelesti.it/extend-content-query-web-part-with-queryoverride/

Comment: @Gaurravs i already check this ,, but seems in SharePoint referencing a site column or content type is the most conflicting topic i have ever deal with , internla names , ids , so i am sure my problem is related to this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your query to get the user field values like this:

```
 <FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" />
    <Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>
```

Comment: but how i can match it to be equal to the current login user ?

Comment: <UserID /> tag does that for you.

Comment: ok i modifed my query as you mentioned but no results will be returned,, i also replace the CT ids with the content type display name,, but still no results will be returned .. can u advice ?

Comment: Ok. I suggest that you test your query using this tool on codeplex. https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok i will try this ,, but what could be causing this ?

Comment: :) i download the tool, i type the site collection URL , then i click load, but the tool stop responding !!!:) so seems i am now facing extra problem instead of solving my current problem :)

Comment: Also your content type value needs to be of type ContentTypeId

Comment: can you adivce which part of my code i do need to update ?

Comment: <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
           <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802</Value>

Comment: thanks again for the help, i will change it and i will try this now,,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31516/discussion-on-answer-by-harryb-how-to-specify-a-caml-query-to-return-items-that).